# How to access properties of BehaviorSubject in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have created the below SubjectBahavior of rxjs.

```
private userData= new BehaviorSubject<any>({
    userId: 0
});
```

Then I have a method checkValue where I check if userData was updated:

```
if(this.userData.userId == 0){
        ...
 }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<any>'.
```

Is there a way to check the value of BehaviorSubject in typescript?

Comment: You could access the value with `this.userData.value.userId` but in general it's better to subscribe

Comment: Or call the getValue method, see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 1):

There two ways to get the current value of the **BehaviorSubject**:

1. use **getValue** method:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

let testBehaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject({userId: 0});
testBehaviorSubject.getValue().userId  // 0
testBehaviorSubject.next({userId: 1})
testBehaviorSubject.getValue().userId  // 1
```

2. **subscribe** to the BehaviorSubject:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

let testBehaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject({userId: 0});
testBehaviorSubject.subscribe((user) => console.log(user.userId))  // 0
testBehaviorSubject.next({userId: 1})
testBehaviorSubject.subscribe((user) => console.log(user.userId))  // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Martin's solution works:

This is how you do it:

this.userData.value.userId

Comment: Be very careful. Directly accessing the internal value of a behaviourSubject is in my experience a rx-antipattern which often leads to convoluted solutions. better to use `.tap(val => console.log(val)` so you can follow it while it changes (or store it in a local variable